# Image hosting on Google App Engine a good idea?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cdn, blobstore, google-cdn

I am planning to host images via Google app engine blobstore API.
It looks to be very promising on performance and cheap.
Also I would be able to map to my custom domain.

But few things that I wish to know about.

**1.) Is serving images via blobstore a good idea in regards to SEO of my application?
As all my images are going to dynamic, does google index dynamic images with my custom domain url.**

**2.)And image serving is going to cost outgoing bandwidth which seems too be cheap but still is there any other alternative to cut off outgoing bandwidth cost?**

**3.) And please suggest if there is any other alternative that is better that GAE and can serve my requirements.**

Answer (score 0):

`1.)Is serving images via blobstore a good idea in regards to SEO of my application? As all my images are going to dynamic, does google index dynamic images with my custom domain url.`

Don't put the images in database. Instead upload the images and put the link in database. Instagram uses s3 for its images, so you don't have to worry about performance. If you store the images as files and provide a link, search engines can index them well. Just make sure you use relevant names for the images.  For example, for [this image](http://www.sweetbellaroos.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/owls_watermark-1024x710.png) use http://example.com/data/image-store/`owl-be-your-valentine`

`3.)And please suggest if there is any other alternative that is better that GAE and can serve my requirements.`

I have not used GAE. If you are asking for an alternative. I would suggest you [aws s3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

`2.)And image serving is going to cost outgoing bandwidth which seems too be cheap but still is there any other alternative to cut off outgoing bandwidth cost?`

s3 is cheap, very cheap. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/using-amazon-s3-as-an-image-hosting-service.html

Comment: AWS S3 could be an alternative but do you find difference in performance while I serve it via app engine blobstore api and amazon S3. Price on both are comaparable to me.

Comment: Also I doubt on the indexing part. my images on app engine are still not indexed. I do followed the meaningful name strategy. Any views on that?

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on daily usage.

Google App Engine has a daily free quota(1GB outgoing traffic).
If you daily taffic around 1-5GB,Google App Engine is the cheapest way.

Comment: What about SEO? Does google index dynamic images served via blobstore?

Answer (score -1):

Whn using Java to host images with GAE, you should use the [getServingUrl](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ImagesService#getServingUrl%28com.google.appengine.api.images.ServingUrlOptions%29).  You pass it a blob key, along with optional resize and crop options, and it gives you back a URL.